# Do Loop not looping

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2003

I have this do loop code in my `Userform`.

```
Private Sub cmdLogin_Click()
Dim user, pass As String
Dim x As Integer

user = Me.user1.Text
pass = Me.pass1.Text

x = 2
Do While ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(x, 1).Value <> ""
    If ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(x, 1).Value = user _
    And ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(x, 2).Value = pass Then
       MsgBox "YES"
       Exit Do
    Else
       MsgBox "NO"
       Exit Do
    End If
Loop
End Sub
```

But it seems like the code does not loop throughout the cells and only stops until x=2 or cells(2,1). This results not being able to go through the whole list of usernames and passwords and every username and pass i enter becomes wrong except the ones at row 2. Please help as i am new to VBA

Comment: @PortlandRunner Post it as answer, I'll delete mine :)

Comment: @PortlandRunner sir, i did place the x = x+1 but it still cant read the correct username and password. This time only the row3 is being determined.

Answer (score 4):

If `Cells(2,1)` is not `""` then you have an infinite loop because you never increment `x`.

Just before `Loop` add this: `x = x + 1` to increment your loop.

I suggest you play with some of [these examples](http://www.excel-easy.com/vba/loop.html) to get an idea of how VBA loops work.

Answer (score 1):

@PortlandRunner i have found the answer. thanks for helpiing. instead of placing x=x+1 right before the loop i did this

```
Do While ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(x, 1).Value <> ""

    If ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(x, 1).Value = user And ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(x, 2).Value = pass Then
       MsgBox "YES"
       Exit Do
    Else
        x = x + 1
       If ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(x, 1).Value = user And ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(x, 2).Value = pass Then
        MsgBox "YES"
       Exit Do
       Else
        MsgBox "NO"
        Exit Do
       End If
    End If
loop
```

thank you so much to the people who helped :)

Answer (score 0):

Just to simplify your own answer Angelo, here are some tips :

```
With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    If (.Cells(x, 1) = user And .Cells(x, 2) = pass) Or _
    (.Cells(x + 1, 1) = user And .Cells(x + 1, 2) = pass) Then
        MsgBox "YES"
        Exit Do
    Else
        MsgBox "NO"
    End If
End With
```